# MySql remote server login issue

Tags: mysql, remote-login

I am using below command on server with ip `y.y.y.y` to connect to DB hosted on `x.x.x.x`

```
mysql -u user -p -h x.x.x.x
```

I am getting below error, I don't why its picking user@y.y even though I have specified -h option

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'y.y.y.y' (using
>   password: YES)

Comment: There is a perfect answer for you: [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/767881). Read `localhost` as your `y.y.y.y`

Comment: In error "user@y.y"  means your current ip is y.y

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following things are true:

- Are your credentials *really* correct? (Host, User, Password, Database, Port)
- Does the server allows remote acces (`bind adress = x.x.x.x`in `my.cnf`)
- Can the host be uniquly identified? (See: [this SQ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)